# How do you Response.Redirect to another website with the same name, but with different port?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two separate websites running locally on my IIS server at work. One is on normal port 80 and the other 90. Now, I have a Default page which makes the users select one of the pictures that will redirect them to the correct website.

It works fine with the port 80, since you don't have to specify which port you are running a normal website, but how can I redirect the second picture to redirect to port 90.

This is the code I have, but it keeps adding a stupid forward slash...

```
Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath + ":90/login.aspx");
```

It ends up showing http://192.168.2.122/:90/login.aspx.

Any help will be gladly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to fetch segments of the current URL.

```
Response.Redirect(
  "http://" + Request.Url.Host + ":90" + 
  Request.ApplicationPath + "/login.aspx");
```

Edit: tweaked to compensate for alternate Application paths (since I did bring it up in a comment).

Answer (score 4):

```
Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd("/") + ":90/login.aspx");
```

Comment: Request.ApplicationPath returns the absolute URL of where the app lives.  By coincidence, this will work for the example, but if the app is in a subdirectory, the redirect will break again.  In the example above, Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd("/") returns an empty string, so the final redirect argument is ":90/login.aspx".  If the app is in a subdirectory, it'll return "/appsubdir:90/login.aspx"